# How to add a flag column based on column values and COUNT() of records partitioned by customer in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL Server table looks like this:

```
 DayNo. Customer    AgentsInvolved  CallID   DesiredFlag
 -------------------------------------------------------
   0      AAA              1        1858          0 
   0      AAA              3        1859          0
   2      AAA              1        1860          0
   0      BBB              2        1862          0
   0      CCC              1        1863          1
   0      DDD              3        1864          0
   9      DDD              1        1865          0
   9      DDD              4        1866          0
```

How do I add a new column to say;

```
WHEN (DayNo. = 0, and AgentsInvolved = 1) AND COUNT(callID) = 1 (grouped by customer)
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0
```

The column values I understand can be wrapped into a case statement but not sure how to add the condition for the `COUNT(CallID)`. See the `DesiredFlag` column to see the result I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM table t1 
                              WHERE t1.Customer = t.Customer AND t1.CallID <> t.CallID
                             ) AND t.DayNo = 0 AND t.AgentsInvolved = 1
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0
        END) AS DesiredFlag
FROM table t;
```

Comment: The total count appears to be off. The query I used to get the correct list was by doing this 
`SELECT Customer, count(1) from 'table' WHERE DayNo = 0 and AgentsInvolved = 1 group by Customer HAVING count(1) = 1`
This gives me a row count different to the summed up flags in your calculated column. Any Ideas?

Comment: @dragonfury2. .  That is what this query does except the `count`.

Comment: Yes I think your query is sound (ignore my last comment). However I dont think Ive correctly explained the logic. So im only interested in flagging those records where the **Customer ONLY exists in DayNo. 0, and AgentsInvolved= 1, and only a single CallID on Day 0.** Im trying to find customers that called only once (first contact always on DayNo.0) and spoke to 1 agent. hope that clears it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

with SAMPLE DATA:

```
declare @T Table (DayNo int,Customer varchar(10),AgentsInvolved int,CallID int)
insert into @T values
(0,'AAA',1,1858),
(0,'AAA',3,1859),
(2,'AAA',1,1860),
(0,'BBB',2,1862),
(0,'CCC',1,1863),
(0,'DDD',3,1864),
(9,'DDD',1,1865),
(9,'DDD',4,1866)
```

you can get your result (as i understand correctly) by:

```
;with summation as
(
    select Customer, count(1) as qty
    from @T
    group by Customer
)
select
    T.*,
    coalesce(F.flag, 0) as flag
from
    @T T
    inner join summation s on s.Customer = T.Customer
    outer apply (select 1 as flag where DayNo = 0 and AgentsInvolved = 1 and qty = 1) F
```

RESULTS:

```
DayNo       Customer   AgentsInvolved CallID      flag
----------- ---------- -------------- ----------- -----------
0           AAA        1              1858        0
0           AAA        3              1859        0
2           AAA        1              1860        0
0           BBB        2              1862        0
0           CCC        1              1863        1
0           DDD        3              1864        0
9           DDD        1              1865        0
9           DDD        4              1866        0
```